# Is there a way to pass Deferred.resolve() arguments to next function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote two functions which return jQuery.Promise object.
The first function makes a file object and passes it to Deferred.resolve().
The second write it to sdcard.

```
function onSuccess(file) {
    writeFile(file)
        .done(onComplete)
        .fail(onFail);
}
makeFileObject()
    .done(onSuccess)
    .fail(onFail);
```

But I want to integrate this two steps as the following.

```
makeFileObject()
    .then(writeFile)
    .done(onComplete)
    .fail(onFail);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just return another promise from `writeFile`. Aren't you doing this already?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? There's a difference in the functionality of <code>.then</code> pre and post 1.8. Also, please post(at least simplified) code of the functions you're using as well.

Comment: The way you've described it, your code should work without a hitch on jquery 1.8+ -> http://jsfiddle.net/R4g9t/

Comment: I thought resolve() arguments should be passed to next function explicitly. But it's not necessary. Thank you.